# Calculate percentual grid layout cell width

Tags: javascript, html, css, gridview

I'm trying to generate a responsive grid layout but I'm not a math genius... No... Really... I'm not.

This ist what I want to do.

1. get the width of the element which contains the grid elements.
2. all grid element have a right and bottom margin from 20px
3. depending on the root elements width the number of cells changes. let's say 5 cells if the width is bigger than 1200px.
4. every :nth(x) ( last element in a row ) gets the margin-right set to 0
5. calculate the percentual width of the cells.

if the last elemet would keep the margin-right everthing would work but in this case the margin must go.

This is everything I'm able to do with my math....^-^

```
var marginRight = 20, viewportWidth = 1200, numcells = 5;
var substract =  marginRight / ( viewportWidth / 100 );
width = 100 / numcells - substract;
```

As said. This would work if the last cells would keep the margin. But they don't and I don't know how to figure it out. May some of the stackoverflowmonks bring the wisdom? That would be awfully nice. Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider working with existing grid systems? Bootstrap e.g.? That you don't have to "reinvent the wheel" again.

Comment: This isn't an option for me. I know there exists a really simple algorithm/formular for this but it's not available in my memory..

Comment: Go for `bootstrap` rather than becoming an genius

Comment: Sorry but no. I can't just include bootstrap in a larger project. Too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:320px) { 
    ._flowed_ { margin-right: 0%;width:100%; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width:481px) { 
    ._flowed_ { margin-right: 0%;width:100%; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width:961px) { 
    ._flowed_ { margin-right: 2.7894%; width: 48.6053%; }
    ._flowed_:nth-child(2n){ margin-right:0; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width:1025px) { 
    ._flowed_ { margin-right: 1.99005%;width: 32.0066%; }
    ._flowed_:nth-child(3n){ margin-right:0; }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width:799px) { 
    ._flowed_ { margin-right: 1.76523%;width: 23.6761%; }
    ._flowed_:nth-child(4n){ margin-right:0; }
}
.fluid-4 ._flowed_:nth-child(4n){margin-right:0;}
.fluid-3 ._flowed_:nth-child(3n){margin-right:0;}
.fluid-2 ._flowed_:nth-child(2n){ margin-right:0; }
.fluid-4 ._flowed_{margin-right: 1.76523%;width: 23.6761%;}
.fluid-3 ._flowed_{margin-right: 1.99005%;width: 32.0066%;}
.fluid-2 ._flowed_{margin-right: 2.7894%;width: 48.6053%;}
.fluid-1 ._flowed_{margin-right: 0%;width:100%;}
```

And a little Javascript to change the classes.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Is there a more elegant solution possible?

```
viewportWidth = 1200, numcells = 5, marginRight = 20;
one   = viewportWidth-(numcells-1)*marginRight;
two   = (one / gridNum);
three =  two / (  viewportWidth / 100  );
```